# Bind Clicked Object to Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Modaal](https://github.com/humaan/Modaal) library and want to dynamically load the content of the modal via Ajax, which requires sending the ID for each clicked item through to the callback.

I think I need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the clicked element to the modaal function, but am not sure how. I think that jQuery's [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Without binding, the popup works (but data is not updated for each item):

```
var info_popup = $('.info-popup');
info_popup.modaal({
    after_open: function(ev){
        console.log(info_popup.data('unique_id'));
    }
});
```

When I bind the function, it returns the data, but a second click is required to launch the modal:

```
$('.info-popup').on('click', function() {
    var unique_id = $(this).data('unique_id');
    return $(this).modaal({
        after_open: function(ev){
            console.log(unique_id);
        }
    });
});
```

So I'm thinking I need to somehow forward the clicked status to Modaal, but not sure how.

## Update

I can achieve this by setting the `start_open` parameter in Modaal to `true`, but not sure if this is an elegant approach, and would like to see how it would be done from *outside* of Modaal.

Comment: do you mean that with first approach it only works for first item of class infopopup ?

Comment: yes. either the first item of possibly the first one that's clicked.